# TestNG order of Test Case execution with priority

Tags: java, selenium, testng

The following are the test methods in `TestNG` test case class:

```
@Test (priority=0)
public void test01() {
}
@Test (priority=1, dependsOnMethods="test01")
public void test02() {
}
@Test (priority=2)
public void test03() {
}
@Test (priority=3)
public void test04() {
}
```

The execution order is `test01 - test03 - test04 - test02`.
Well this seems incorrect, because, by the time `test02` is reached, the dependent test method `test01` is already executed. Hence the `test02` should get executed immediately. The correct order, I feel, is `test01 - test02 - test03 - test04`

Is this a bug in the `TestNG` or is this deliberate for some particular reason that I am missing ?

Comment: I think it might be a bug, as you are mixing 2 ways of scheduling tests (`priority` and `dependsOn*`). If you need to fix this soon, use one or the other, but not both. It's also important to say that unit tests shouldn't have interdependencies like this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't provide priority and depends on together, you can group the tests. You can do it like :

```
@Test(priority = 1, groups = { "qty" })
public void increaseQty() {
    System.out.println("in increase qty");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "increaseQty" }, groups = { "qty" })
public void decreaseQty() {
    System.out.println("in decrease qty");
}

@Test(dependsOnGroups = { "qty" })
public void removeFromCart() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("remove qty");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "removeFromCart" })
public void emptyCart() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("empty Cart");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a TestNG already known issue: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/474

And the fix will be available in the next release (maybe 6.9.14): https://github.com/cbeust/testng/pull/1158