# TestNG:I got Stuck in below issue in dependsonMethods

Tags: testng

```
My code looks like as below .I have 3 methods Method1,Method2,Method3).first methods looks like below



 public void Method1() 
      {                   
        ...some Operations....
         }
```

As we know second method(Method2) executes when ever Method1 get pass otherwise it will be skipped due to 'dependsOnMethods' concept.

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods ={"Method1"})
 public void Method2() 
      { 
        ...some Operations....
         }


My Problem was when we go to method 3.I have some confusion.that are given in note as detail.

 @Test(dependsOnMethods ={"Method1","Method2"})
     public void Method3() 
          {                   
            ...some Operations....
             }
```

Note:
For my code Method 2 is optional,But Method1 is mandatory.so i use the Method1 as 'dependsOnMethods' for both test methods(Method2,Method3).For my above code method3 is till not working as expected.
1.If method1 pass,Method2 pass means Method3 is executes properly.
2.If method1 fails,All are executes properly as skipped.

but below scenarios it will not working.
3.If method1 pass,but Method2 fail means for my scenarios method3 will be executed.But It will not work now due to 'dependsOnMethods ={"Method1","Method2"}'.
can u provide me as suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, `Method3` (like `Method2`) is only dependent of `Method1`.
If you want a specific order between `Method2` and `Method3`, you can set a different `priority`.

Note: It won't work with the current version of TestNG but a fix will be available in the next release (you can check with the snapshot version). Check my comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/39331387/4234729

Comment: I will check and inform u for further details.if it not works.